# script to Snapshot mysql db on Amazon EBS

Tags: mysql, backup, yum, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I did search for the relevant questions and still couldnt find any answers in the forum.
I am working on a simple script to automate snapshotting mysql db on amazon ebs. My instance is hosted on amazon linux image. The scripts I find online are either written for debian or those which are run from my computer and not from the server which need key-value pair. I am quite sure .pem file is not needed to create a snapshot from the server.

Comment: You're much more likely to find an answer to this on serverfault.com than you are here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @OllieJones can you please let me now how I can shift this question the serverfault site?

Comment: Just go there and ask it. If five people on SO vote to close it (like I did) it will shift there automatically.  But why wait for that?